# Fetch an request in Python (OpenGraph)

Tags: python, web, export, facebook-opengraph

I want to fetch the following array to get the first item price.
[https://opensea.io/assets/neon-district-season-one-item?search[query]=mimir%20assault&search[sortAscending]=true&search[sortBy]=PRICE&search[stringTraits][0][name]=Armor%20Slot&search[stringTraits][0][values][0]=Body&search[stringTraits][1][name]=rarity&search[stringTraits][1][values][0]=Common](https://opensea.io/assets/neon-district-season-one-item?search%5Bquery%5D=mimir%20assault&search%5BsortAscending%5D=true&search%5BsortBy%5D=PRICE&search%5BstringTraits%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=Armor%20Slot&search%5BstringTraits%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=Body&search%5BstringTraits%5D%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=rarity&search%5BstringTraits%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D=Common)

I have tried to **Insepect the code** and get the **API request**, export it to **Postman** and get the code on Python. However, it is not working. I continued investigating the request and it is not a normal http request (API REST), it contains some application structure (**OpenGraph**) which I never lead with that. I am doing several tests changing the input parameters but i am a bit struggled there.

Somecan can lead me? Thank you.

Comment: You will need the *requests* module and *bs4* and possibly *selenium* if you're working with dynamic web pages

Comment: thank you for the reply; however request module is already imported to fetch, bs4 is for html beautify/extraction (i still did not receive any content yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def getHTML(address):
    try:
        req = urllib.request.Request(address)
        req.add_header(
            'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36')
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
            charset = response.headers.get_content_charset()
            if not charset:
                charset = 'utf-8'  # guess
            return response.read().decode(charset)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    # If anygoes wrong, return None


url = 'https://opensea.io/assets/neon-district-season-one-item?search[query]=mimir%20assault&search[sortAscending]=true&search[sortBy]=PRICE&search[stringTraits][0][name]=Armor%20Slot&search[stringTraits][0][values][0]=Body&search[stringTraits][1][name]=rarity&search[stringTraits][1][values][0]=Common'
html = getHTML(url)
if html:
    soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thank you! I could reach the website. However, how could i get more items not only the first 32? If you realized, when you scroll down, additional items appears

Comment: You may find **selenium** helpful in this case

Comment: thanks for the info! I did it using selenium